# OpenJPA - Create SQL Script instead of directly executing Queries

Tags: sql, jpa, db2, openjpa

I'm currently working on a small OpenJPA application.

I was wondering whether it is possible to not have the queries executed as I am persisting some objects, but rather print the SQL statements to some file.
That way, I would be able to review the changes to be made to the database before executing them.

I know that OpenJPA allows me to do `SQL=TRACE` to print the statements, but doesn't keep them from being executed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is an easy way to do it. If you aren't afraid of digging in, I'm sure you could extend the OpenJPA runtime to add this sort of support.